# Integral of a normal function multiplied by heaviside and delta functions

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2t}u(\tau - t)t^{2}\delta(t)dt$

Hi! How would I go about computing this integral? I understand I can change one of the integration limits and eliminate the heaviside function, but I'm not exactly sure what to do with the delta. I also know that $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(t)\delta(\tau-t)dt = f(\tau)$, so should I just treat $e^{2t}t^2$ as $f(t)$? Or do I have to integrate by parts and leave the delta on the side?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes, I think that you can treat $e^{2t}t^2$ like $f(t)$ as long as it is continuous at the center of the $\delta(t)$ (i.e., $t=0$).

Answer (score 0):

This integral is zero, since if $f(t) = e^{2t} u(\tau - t) t^2$ then $$\int_{- \infty}^{+ \infty} f(t) \delta(t) \, dt = f(0) = e^{0} u(\tau) 0^2 = 0.$$